# Need to allow encoded slashes on Apache

Tags: apache, apache2, apache-config

I'm currently trying to place a URL within a URL. For example:

```
http://example.com/url/http%3A%2F%2Fwww.url2.com
```

I'm aware that I have to encode the URL, which I have done, but now I am getting a `404` error back from the server rather than my app. I think my problem lies with apache and can be fixed with the `AllowEncodedSlashes On` directive.

I've tried putting the directive at the bottom of the httpd.conf to no effect, and am unsure what to do next. Am I putting it in the right place? If so, does anyone have any other solutions?

Comment: In addition to https://stackoverflow.com/a/9933890/6333217 :
If you use `RewriteRule` instead of `ProxyPass` you should add `NE` flag to avoid decoding.

Answer (score 68, accepted):

This issue is not related to Apache Bug 35256. Rather, it is related to Bug 46830. The `AllowEncodedSlashes` setting is not inherited by virtual hosts, and virtual hosts are used in many default Apache configurations, such as the one in Ubuntu. The workaround is to add the `AllowEncodedSlashes` setting inside a `<VirtualHost>` container (`/etc/apache2/sites-available/default` in Ubuntu).

[Bug 35256](https://issues.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=35256): `%2F` will be decoded in PATH_INFO (Documentation to `AllowEncodedSlashes` says no decoding will be done)

[Bug 46830](https://issues.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=46830): If `AllowEncodedSlashes On` is set in the global context, it is not inherited by virtual hosts. You must explicitly set `AllowEncodedSlashes On` in every `<VirtalHost>` container.

The documentation for how the different configuration sections are merged says:

> Sections inside `<VirtualHost>` sections are applied after the corresponding sections outside the virtual host definition. This allows virtual hosts to override the main server configuration.

Answer (score 121):

I kept coming across this post for another issue. Let me just explain real quick.

I had the same style URL and was also trying to proxy it.

Example: Proxy requests from `/example/` to another server.

```
/example/http:%2F%2Fwww.someurl.com/
```

**Issue 1:** Apache believes that's an invalid url

Solution: `AllowEncodedSlashes On` in httpd.conf

**Issue 2:** Apache decodes the encoded slashes

Solution: `AllowEncodedSlashes NoDecode` in httpd.conf (Requires Apache 2.3.12+)

**Issue 3:** mod_proxy attempts to re-encode (double encode) the URL changing `%2F` to `%252F` (eg. `/example/http:%252F%252Fwww.someurl.com/`)

Solution: In `httpd.conf` use the `ProxyPass` keyword `nocanon` to pass the raw URL thru the proxy.

```
ProxyPass http://anotherserver:8080/example/ nocanon
```

httpd.conf file:

```
AllowEncodedSlashes NoDecode

<Location /example/>
  ProxyPass http://anotherserver:8080/example/ nocanon
</Location>
```

Reference:

- http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_proxy.html
- http://www.silverdisc.co.uk/blog/2009/02/28/url-canonicalisation-and-normalisation
- [Cannot match %2F in mod_rewrite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7544759/cannot-match-2f-in-mod-rewrite)

Comment: The first two issues were pretty well documented around the net, but issue 3 was a tough nut to crack till I saw this answer. *THANK YOU*.

Comment: Wow.  Perfect answer, works, concise.  Please make this the accepted answer.

Comment: It took me ages to find this answer. Sometimes one upvote is simply not enough. Many thanks!

Comment: Thanks so much for this; the exact thing that was needed.

Comment: works a charm when using ProxyPass. Fixed an issue with magento API when using SKU codes containing a slash.

Comment: If you are using balancer, you should add `nocanon` to `ProxyPass` directive not `BalancerMember`.
Example: `ProxyPass /webservice balancer://api/webservice nocanon`
Thanks to @stenix https://stackoverflow.com/a/14339060/8433375

Comment: My problem was a little different, but `nocanon` resolved it. I have a GiLab omnibus installation behind a Apache proxy with SSL and some urls (the ones with slashes) failed to go through. Using `canon`fixed it! So glad I came across this.

Answer (score 33):

I wasted a great many hours on this problem too.  I'm a bit late to the party, but it seems there's a solution now.

As per [this thread](https://issues.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=35256), there is (was) a bug in Apache such that if you have `AllowEncodedSlashes On`, it prevents the 404, but it mistakenly **decodes** the slashes, which is incorrect according to the RFC.

[This comment](https://issues.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=35256#c16) offers a solution, namely to use:

```
AllowEncodedSlashes NoDecode
```

Answer (score 4):

in light of all the hassles, i opted for base64_encoding followed by urlencoding.  It works without having to fool around with apache server settings or looking at bug reports.  It also works without having to put the url in the query section.

```
$enc_url = urlencode(base64_encode($uri_string));
```

and to get it back

```
$url = base64_decode(urldecode($enc_url));
```

> `http://example.com/admin/supplier_show/8/YWRtaW4vc3VwcGxpZXJz`
>
> `http://example.com/admin/supplier_show/93/YWRtaW4vc3VwcGxpZXJzLzEwMA%3D%3D`

Comment: I don't like it, but ended up going this way too

Comment: You will get the same problem here, because '/' is a base64 character.

Comment: A urlencoded `/` regardless of the method to make it is still a `%2F` is it not?

Comment: The top comment on the php.net website for base64_encode() has a good solution for a URL-safe version: http://php.net/manual/en/function.base64-encode.php#103849

Basically it involves replacing + and / with alternative chars on encode/decode.

Answer (score 3):

After a fair bit of testing, and looking at the bug in Apache, I've concluded that despite offered solutions in different forums, this is an unresolved issue in Apache.  See the bug: https://issues.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=35256

The workaround that works for me is to refactor the URI so that the item that can contain the escaped slashes is in the query section of the URI, instead of the path.  My tests show that when they are there, they don't get filtered out by Apache, no matter the AllowEncodedSlashes and AcceptPathInfo settings.

So:     `http://test.com/url?http%3A%2F%2Fwww.url2.com`

or:  `http://test.com/url?theURL=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.url2.com`

instead of:  `http://test.com/url/http%3A%2F%2Fwww.url2.com`

This means an architecture change for our project, but it seems unavoidable.  Hope you found a solution.

Comment: Hi Rob. Yeah, I got the same result, so had to implement the architecture change too. Little disappointing, but just glad that it works at this stage. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Replace `%2F` with `%252F` at the client side.

This is the double-encoded form of the forward slash.

So when it reaches the server and gets prematurely decoded it will decode it to %2F which is exactly what you want.

Comment: You should never every double encode: https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3986#section-2.4

Comment: @koppor But you can double-decode it if you know it has been double-encoded.  So you could double-encode that entire component, and then do a second decode on that component on the other side?

Answer (score 0):

I'm getting the same problem with "AllowEncodedSlashes On", and have tried placing the directive in a couple different places: apache2.conf, httpd.conf, and inside a  section, as per an example at   http://www.jampmark.com/web-scripting/5-solutions-to-url-encoded-slashes-problem-in-apache.html.

If you haven't already, you might want to set your logging level to debug (another directive) and see if you get the error:

found %2f (encoded '/') in URI (decoded='/url/http://www.url2.com'), returning 404

other not found errors don't provide this info in the logs.  Just another diagnostic...

Good luck (to both of us)!