# How to redirect url with %2F using .htaccess in php

Tags: php, .htaccess, url, redirect

I am trying to redirect URL http://www.example.com/author/Hermann+%2F+Kohn
TO http://www.example.com/author/Hermann+Kohn using .htaccess file in php but not able to achieve target result.

So can anyone please guide how to achieve it

Comment: what have you tried to achieve the desired result?Any google or Stack search ?

Comment: related to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7544759/cannot-match-2f-in-mod-rewrite?