# weblogic proxy in Apache rejecting the request containing encoded slashes error log - "Rejecting double-encoded URI"

Tags: apache, weblogic-10.x

I am using Apache Server + Weblogic for my application. Apache seem to reject any uri with encoded slash.

I have tried setting AllowEncodedSlashes On/NoDecode in httpd.conf

But NoDecode seem to double encode the URI with 404 response , the weblogic proxy logs shows the following error "Rejecting double-encoded URI".I found no reference for this error.

I doubt the problem is with Apache but with the weblogic proxy. Can anyone help here ?

Comment: Did you ever get an answer to this?

Answer (score 0):

Adding

```
    AllowEncodedSlashes On
```

to the vhost config in Apache resolved the problem for our weblogic 10 setup.

More details here: [Need to allow encoded slashes on Apache](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4390436/need-to-allow-encoded-slashes-on-apache)