# Laravel PHP - send JSON object with GET method

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

i have problems with my Webservice i created in php with the Laravel Framework.

I have the following URL to call:

```
http://localhost:100/cust/server.php/InitialSync/{"IdCard": "lxpIu1bD4UX4W2h5EM+i6VEQUZk+i\/SJF1DU6179HBejWkOBENSflnTSN\/8N14OGTqh6fH\/6kNrjJCilCMIrVtrlUAyQ5y8zZXVy5K3XwMOGmlHghAe80Q=="}
```

So you see that i send a Json Object with an crypted IdCard to the Server.
My route looks like that:

```
Route::get('InitialSync/{idCard}, 'SyncController@InitialSync'};
```

So Problem is that this won´t work. I think the Problems are the / in the JsonObject.

Does anyone of you know how i can solve this problem.

The Result from Laravel is:

```
Symfony \ Component \ HttpKernel \ Exception \ NotFoundHttpException
```

I think he tries to find the Route but becouse of the / in the Json Object i get this error.

Comment: What kind of error is returned ? Your URL is strange. Why are you using port 100 ? What is cust path ?
What is **server.php** file ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Need to allow encoded slashes on Apache](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4390436/need-to-allow-encoded-slashes-on-apache)

Comment: so, you think it´s a problem with apache?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately Laravel can't undestand   your browser will have trouble to process a JSON sent via GET, even if you encode and stringify it via Javascript:

```
encodeURIComponent(
  JSON.stringify(
    {"IdCard": "lxpIu1bD4UX4W2h5EM+i6VEQUZk+i\/SJF1DU6179HBejWkOBENSflnTSN\/8N14OGTqh6fH\/6kNrjJCilCMIrVtrlUAyQ5y8zZXVy5K3XwMOGmlHghAe80Q=="}
  )
)
```

Wich generates this string:

```
"%7B%22IdCard%22%3A%22lxpIu1bD4UX4W2h5EM%2Bi6VEQUZk%2Bi%2FSJF1DU6179HBejWkOBENSflnTSN%2F8N14OGTqh6fH%2F6kNrjJCilCMIrVtrlUAyQ5y8zZXVy5K3XwMOGmlHghAe80Q%3D%3D%22%7D"
```

Laravel will still have matters to recognize a route in that URL. **This will not work**.

The source of the problem is the escaped characters `\/` present in the string. **So you have some options**:

1) Send it via POST

2) Base64 encode the IdCard and decode is back in Laravel.

3) Replace those characters by something else and revert it in Laravel.

4) Fill a bug in Laravel's Github repo and wait for them to fix it.

Comment: okay, i tried your solution now and i have the same problem i get error 404. My Problem is that i send a crypted string (AES) and my Laravel Route has to accept that.

Comment: My solution? I gave no solution, I gave you 3 options and none of those is a solution. After the code I shown I said `Laravel will still have matters to recognize a route in that URL.`, which means that not even this will make it work.

Comment: okay... so that means, i have no change to handle this with a Get Request. So the only Solution is to make a Post and not a Get. Do you agree with this?

Comment: Yeah, if you can make a POST, it will succeed, but sometimes we just can't. Just edited to add this to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

1) on your router:

```
Route::get('/readjson/{json}', 'MyController@readJson');
```

2) on your controller:

```
class MyController extends BaseController {

    public function readJson() {
        dd(request()->segments());
    }
}
```

That should print all the segments of the requested URI, including the param sent as a JSON string

3) Then just replace segments() with segment(n) to get the exact one. Should be number 2 in this case or 3 if you're using api routes (routes/api.php). From there you can use json_decode or anything else to decode the JSON string.