# htaccess howto rewrite an encoded slash in url

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have URL with an encoded slash (`%2F`) and I cannot get rewrite rules to catch this correctly.

My URL is:

```
http://example.com/some-path/description%2Frest-of-description/1101
```

I've tried rewrites like:-

```
# is the %2F interpreted as a path separator
RewriteRule ^some-path/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)$ /property/view?ref=$3 [B,R=301,L]
# or is it as an encoded string
RewriteRule ^some-path/(.*)%2F(.*)/(.*)$ /property/view?ref=$3 [B,R=301,L]
# or even double encoded
RewriteRule ^some-path/(.*)%252F(.*)/(.*)$ /villas/$1-$2/$3 [B,R=301,NE,L]
```

I've also tried adding `QSA` to above.

There is a similar question on SO [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/591694/url-encoded-slash-in-url) but it's IIS and .NET based

I'm running LAMP stack

Comment: Check this: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/core.html#allowencodedslashes

Comment: @Nikhil You should add that as an answer (with a bit more info).

Comment: I tried adding AllowEncodedSlashes On to vhosts and get 500 on all requests ... apache 2.4

Comment: Just to confirm, with `AllowEncodedSlashes Off` (default) do you get a _system generated_ 404 (ie. the server's default 404, not a custom 404 page)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For security reasons Apache deny `%2F`. See [urlencoded Forward slash is breaking URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3235219/urlencoded-forward-slash-is-breaking-url)

You can turn off this with [`AllowEncodedSlashes`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#allowencodedslashes) directive in your server config.

But it would be better if you encode the URL if you have control of this part of the code.

Comment: thx but can't get it to work.  Gives a 500 if placed either in httpd.conf or the vhosts. Maybe an OSX error (my dev machine) ... will try on a linux machine later.

Comment: Look if this post brings some help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4390436/need-to-allow-encoded-slashes-on-apache

Comment: Yes, that's got it - thx!  Just for the record, I can't encode the urls differently as they are already in google index.  In fact, in trying to remap them, I came across this error.