# apache redirecting a redirect from http to https

Tags: apache, redirect, webserver

I've tried different apache configurations but somehow couldn't crack this. 
I'm forcefully redirecting all URLs from http to https using `Redirect permanent / https://jenkins.example.net/`

However, there is a problem as one of the source URLs has `/redirect` string appended in the end. I learnt that apache **CANNOT** redirect a redirect. Since, the source URL has `redirect` string in the URL, it's not redirecting again to https and resulting as a 404 page.

This is my virtualhost configuration.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

   ServerName jenkins.example.net

   # Redirects traffic to https
   RewriteEngine On

   RewriteRule ^(.*)/redirect /$1 [L,NC]

   Redirect permanent / https://jenkins.example.net/

</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>

   proxyRequests                 Off

   ProxyPreserveHost             On

   AllowEncodedSlashes NoDecode

   ProxyPass        / http://127.0.0.1:8080/ nocanon

   ProxyPassReverse / http://127.0.0.1:8080/

   ServerName jenkins.example.net

   ErrorLog /etc/ssl/error_log

   SSLEngine on

   SSLCertificateFile /etc/ssl/certs/fopjenkins.pem

   SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/ssl/certs/fopjenkins.key

   RequestHeader set X-Forwarded-Proto "https"

   RequestHeader set X-Forwarded-Port "443"

</VirtualHost>
```

I tried above RewriteRule to strip off `/redirect` from the URL but it's not working.

Any help would be highly appreciated..

Additional details (debug output of curl)::

```
[root@rhel-7 ~]# curl -v http://jenkins.example.net/job/STUFOP/job/deploy_os/job/master/5/display/redirect
* About to connect() to jenkins.example.net port 80 (#0)
*   Trying 10.10.11.210...
* Connected to jenkins.example.net (10.10.11.210) port 80 (#0)
> GET /job/STUFOP/job/deploy_os/job/master/5/display/redirect HTTP/1.1
> User-Agent: curl/7.29.0
> Host: jenkins.example.net
> Accept: */*
>
< HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
< Date: Tue, 13 Aug 2019 07:52:00 GMT
< Server: Apache/2.4.6 (Red Hat Enterprise Linux) OpenSSL/1.0.2k-fips
< Location: https://jenkins.example.net/job/STUFOP/job/deploy_os/job/master/5/display/redirect
< Content-Length: 298
< Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1
<
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
<html><head>
<title>301 Moved Permanently</title>
</head><body>
<h1>Moved Permanently</h1>
<p>The document has moved <a href="https://jenkins.example.net/job/STUFOP/job/deploy_os/job/master/5/display/redirect">here</a>.</p>
</body></html>
* Connection #0 to host jenkins.example.net left intact
```

curl -vL debug output::

```
[root@rhel-7 ~]# curl -vL http://jenkins.example.net/job/STUFOP/job/deploy_os/job/master/5/display/redirect
* About to connect() to jenkins.example.net port 80 (#0)
*   Trying 10.10.11.210...
* Connected to jenkins.example.net (10.10.11.210) port 80 (#0)
> GET /job/STUFOP/job/deploy_os/job/master/5/display/redirect HTTP/1.1
> User-Agent: curl/7.29.0
> Host: jenkins.example.net
> Accept: */*
>
< HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
< Date: Tue, 13 Aug 2019 07:58:15 GMT
< Server: Apache/2.4.6 (Red Hat Enterprise Linux) OpenSSL/1.0.2k-fips
< Location: https://jenkins.example.net/job/STUFOP/job/deploy_os/job/master/5/display/redirect
< Content-Length: 298
< Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1
<
* Ignoring the response-body
* Connection #0 to host jenkins.example.net left intact
* Issue another request to this URL: 'https://jenkins.example.net/job/STUFOP/job/deploy_os/job/master/5/display/redirect'
* Found bundle for host jenkins.example.net: 0x986fd0
* About to connect() to jenkins.example.net port 443 (#1)
*   Trying 10.10.11.210...
* Connected to jenkins.example.net (10.10.11.210) port 443 (#1)
* Initializing NSS with certpath: sql:/etc/pki/nssdb
*   CAfile: /etc/pki/tls/certs/ca-bundle.crt
  CApath: none
* Server certificate:*       
*       start date: Jul 16 06:42:46 2019 GMT
*       expire date: Jul 15 06:42:46 2021 GMT
*       common name: jenkins.example.net
* NSS error -8179 (SEC_ERROR_UNKNOWN_ISSUER)
* Peer's Certificate issuer is not recognized.
* Closing connection 1
curl: (60) Peer's Certificate issuer is not recognized.
More details here: http://curl.haxx.se/docs/sslcerts.html

curl performs SSL certificate verification by default, using a "bundle"
 of Certificate Authority (CA) public keys (CA certs). If the default
 bundle file isn't adequate, you can specify an alternate file
 using the --cacert option.
If this HTTPS server uses a certificate signed by a CA represented in
 the bundle, the certificate verification probably failed due to a
 problem with the certificate (it might be expired, or the name might
 not match the domain name in the URL).
If you'd like to turn off curl's verification of the certificate, use
 the -k (or --insecure) option.
[root@rhel-7 ~]# echo $?
60
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably your branch contains `/`, so your url is `STUFOP%2Fdeploy_toolchain`. Apache encode such url and the final is `STUFOP%252Fdeploy_toolchain`.

try this configuration for non secure virtualhost:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
   ServerName jenkins.example.net
   # this prevent encoding
   AllowEncodedSlashes on
   Redirect permanent / https://jenkins.example.net/
</VirtualHost>
```

This configuration should avoid encoding and, according to [Redirect Request to SSL](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/httpd/RedirectSSL) Apache wiki page, all request are redirected to secure virtualhost.

In secure virtualhost, try this configuration:

```
<VirtualHost *:443>

   ServerName jenkins.example.net

   AllowEncodedSlashes on

   proxyRequests                 Off
   ProxyPreserveHost             On
   ProxyPassMatch "^/(.*)/redirect$" "http://127.0.0.1:8080/$1"
   ProxyPass        / http://127.0.0.1:8080/ nocanon 
   ProxyPassReverse / http://127.0.0.1:8080/

   ErrorLog /etc/ssl/error_log

   SSLEngine on 
   SSLCertificateFile /etc/ssl/certs/fopjenkins.pem 
   SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/ssl/certs/fopjenkins.key 
   RequestHeader set X-Forwarded-Proto "https" 
   RequestHeader set X-Forwarded-Port "443"

</VirtualHost>
```

This configuration should avoid encoding and use `ProxyPassMatch` to manipulate url.

Here is some useful link that I've used: [%2F slash encoding issues](https://www.bountysource.com/issues/37202212-2f-slash-encoding-issues), [encode URL wihthin URL - apache mod-proxy (ProxyPass)](https://serverfault.com/questions/715242/encode-url-wihthin-url-apache-mod-proxy-proxypass), [%2F slash encoding issues #399](https://github.com/jenkinsci/gitlab-plugin/issues/399), [htaccess howto rewrite an encoded slash in url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34451993/htaccess-howto-rewrite-an-encoded-slash-in-url)

Comment: Super Thanks Lety for your help. I just had to make some change to the `ProxyPassMatch` by changing the URI from `/redirect` to `/display/redirect` as with display URL wasn't working fine. 

Much appreciated..

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that your `https` redirect happening first and then on `https` the `/redirect` becomes a `404`.

Easiest fix would be to add `RewriteRule ^(.*)/redirect /$1 [L,NC]` to the `<VirtualHost *:443>` block, just to make sure that such a url goes back to home

Comment: Hi, After digging deeper, I learnt on redirect `%252F` is getting appended to the url. When I replace `%252F` with `%2F`, it works. Any idea why it's happening?
I did apply your solution, but it didn't work.

Comment: Something is encoding the url and that too twice. `%252F` is `%2F` encoded, and `%2F` is `/` encoded. Please add the output of the `curl` command I asked earlier in comments

Comment: added.. but somehow it errored out with exit code 60

Comment: Output is too big and can't be pasted here. Unfortunately, don't have access to pastebins at my workplace..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/197858/discussion-between-tarun-lalwani-and-harshavmb).