# migrating TYPO3 6.2.31 to TYPO3 7.6.23

Tags: typo3, typo3-6.2.x, typo3-7.6.x

When I try to migrate my TYPO3 6.2.31 to 7.6.23 I've got some problems.

Especially the page tree is missing so I got this error

`The requested resource "%2Fmain" was not found`

I've tried this way to migrate:

1.) Copy the whole page

2.) Changing the symlinks to the new sources

3.) Starting the migration wizard in install tool

And now When I want to access the backend I got the above mentioned error.

what can I do?

thanks.

When I call url.de/typo3 the follwing url is called:

```
index.php?route=%252Fmain&token=XXX
```

The correct one should be

```
index.php?route=%2Fmain&token=XXX
```

What could be the problem in the url?

Comment: Try deleting caches via installtool (or hole typo3temp). Did seen the same in TYPO3 8.7, which helped in this case. Sometimes OPcode/APC can be the issue, if you change symlinks.

Comment: Yes I already have cleared all cache. In the error massage the following hint is linked: https://wiki.typo3.org/Exception/CMS/1425389240

Comment: but this does not work in my context because I cannot import anything... only the error message is shown

Comment: Did you followed `Check for broken extensions` from installTool?

Comment: yes no problems

Comment: Are you using https?

Comment: yes I use https

Comment: Did you found a solution. We have same issue, since switch to SSL. Only backend is broken, as soon as we are logged in. Different machines tested. Hoster self said - he can login. Same installation on other hosts running without problems.

Comment: Yes I found the Problem! 

Typo3 was running in a docker container and the routing was done as proxy Reverse in isp config.

Comment: You have to configure the proxy correctly. I post the solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as mentioned here: [Need to allow encoded slashes on Apache](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4390436/need-to-allow-encoded-slashes-on-apache)

Issue 1: Apache believes that's an invalid url

Solution: `AllowEncodedSlashes` On in httpd.conf

Issue 2: Apache decodes the encoded slashes

Solution: `AllowEncodedSlashes NoDecode` in httpd.conf (Requires Apache 2.3.12+)

Issue 3: mod_proxy attempts to re-encode (double encode) the URL changing %2F to

```
%252F (eg. /example/http:%252F%252Fwww.someurl.com/)
```

Solution: In httpd.conf use the ProxyPass keyword nocanon to pass the raw URL thru the proxy.

```
ProxyPass http://anotherserver:8080/example/ nocanon
```

httpd.conf file:

```
AllowEncodedSlashes NoDecode

<Location /example/>
  ProxyPass http://anotherserver:8080/example/ nocanon
</Location>
```

Answer (score 1):

Please follow below steps.

1. Download typo3 7 LTS latest source and create symlink.
2. Add your typo3conf, uploads and fileadmin folder
3. Open install tools and clear both cache php and typo3.
4. Compare currentdatabse specification and perform all steps.
5. Go to upgrade wizard and complete all needed steps
6. Clear cache and remove typo3temp file and open BE

Comment: Thanks tried this, but I got the same error Message

Comment: Any hints for me?

Comment: you need to check log history. i think you can determine your problems on this way..

Comment: also don't use **Stop Page Tree**
 for root template

Comment: I'm a bit closer to the problem! Backend works ... Problem added in question above

Comment: if use realurl then disable it and remove .htaccess file

Comment: realurl is disabled and I have only a htaccess with a passwd hat the momet