# .htaccess mod_rewrite with encoded URL path not working while unencoded path works

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am newby on working with mod_rewrite on apache and I am currently trying to write an url-shortener that takes an URL like `mydomain/s/short/{UriToShorten}` and shortens the given URI.

**What happens**
When I pass an URI to the shortening route in my browser, like `localhost/s/short/http://example.com` , the script shorten.php is invoked and the shortening process works as expected. However, if I encode the URL-Component and pass an URI like `localhost/s/short/http%3A%2F%2Fexample.com` (which should be the correct use), I get the message

> **Not Found** 
>   The requested URL /s/short/http://example.com was not found on this server.

And debugging indicates, that neither shorten.php or index.php got run (so I believe, that the server really tries to search a subdirectory `http:` of `short`). This seems to happen independently where the slash encoding %2F is.

**What is expected**
I would expect, that the encoded version works, and maybe the unencoded URI will lead to an error (since URL-Encoding is specifily made to avoid those errors).

**What I use** 
I use the following as .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /s/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^short/(.*)$ shorten.php?url=$1 [L,NC]
RewriteRule ^([a-z0-9]{5})$ index.php?slug=$1 [L,NC]
```

My folder structure is:

```
-www
  -s
    -.htaccess
    -shorten.php
    -index.php
```

and my Apache version is `Apache/2.4.33`

**What I tried** 
Since I have no idea, why this happens, I could only search the mod_rewrite documentation and tried adding the [NE] Flag, that obviously didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is happening because Apache blocks encoded slashes by default. Since Apache 2, it's possible to allow them:
https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#allowencodedslashes

However, be careful about setting `AllowEncodedSlashes On`. This is a security measure made by Apache.

> If encoded slashes are needed in path info, use of NoDecode is strongly recommended as a security measure. Allowing slashes to be decoded could potentially allow unsafe paths.

If you want to enable encoded slashes, use `AllowEncodedSlashes NoDecode` instead. For example:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  [...]

  AllowEncodedSlashes NoDecode

</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I found out what was causing the Problem:

The error did not occur on every encoded url character, but always when the URL contained %2F. So my Problem seems to be [this SO question about encoded Slashes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4390436/need-to-allow-encoded-slashes-on-apache)

I needed to set `AllowEncodedSlashes NoDecode` (or ON) in `httpd.conf` **AND** in `httpd-vhosts.conf` to make it work.

Lesson Learned: Always Check the httpd.conf-features and turn on features explicitely, that you would expect to be on by default