# How to prevent content-spoofing on Apache 2.4?

Tags: apache, apache2.4, apache-config

The below URL is an example of content-spoofing. I need to show my 404 page when I hit a URL like below:

> http://www.example.com/you%27re%20are%20looking%20for%20was%20not%20found%20on%20this%20server%20Please%20visit%20this%20webpage%20to%20fix%20the%20issue%20%28http%3a%2f%2fmalicious.site.evil.com%2f.%20Again%2cthe%20page%20

Currently I see Apache's default error page as below:

> The requested URL /you're are looking for was not found on this server
>   Please visit this webpage to fix the issue
>   (http://malicious.site.evil.com/. Again,the page was not found on this
>   server.

I have tried adding RewriteCond in .htaccess. I have also tried adding the below

> AllowEncodedSlashes NoDecode

at the end of httpd.conf file as mentioned in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4390436/need-to-allow-encoded-slashes-on-apache).

But nothing seems to be working.

Can someone please help?

**Update**

Below is snippet of .htaccess

```
ErrorDocument 404 /404.html

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteRule ^ /404.html [L,R=404]
```

Comment: Just use a custom error document?

Comment: I have custom error page in place in .htaccess. But how do I redirect URLs mentioned above to display my error page?

Comment: If you've correctly configured your custom error you shouldn't need to

Comment: Updated question with .htaccess snippet.

Comment: are .htaccess files enabled in your server configuration and are they allowed to set the `ErrorDocument`?

Comment: also note that apache recommends against the use of .htaccess files unless you don't have access to the server configuration

Comment: Yes, .htaccess file is enabled in server configuration and allowed to set ErrorDocument. I also have access to server configuration.

Answer (score 0):

Fix is “simple” but needs to be applied to every vulnerable vhost explicitly

```
VirtualHost *:80
[...]

AllowEncodedSlashes nodecode

/VirtualHost>



 VirtualHost *:433
[...]

AllowEncodedSlashes nodecode

/VirtualHost
```

dont forget the < at the start of virtual host