# Laravel 8 Encoded Forward Slashes

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8, url-parameters

Laravel 8 documentation says that I can use forward slashes as part of an URL parameter:

https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/routing#parameters-encoded-forward-slashes

It's not working for me. I did:

```
Route::get('/testslash/{param}', function($param) {
    return $param;
})->where('param', '.*');
```

Calling it with
/testslash/test%2Ftest

Results in a 404 page not found.

When using a parameter without slash, the page is loaded showing the parameter value as expected.

Do I maybe have to set another particular laravel option to make this work?

Comment: are you using `/` or `%` between your parameter text?

Comment: `Encoded forward slashes are only supported within the last route segment.`

Comment: I don't see a problem in the code. I, in fact, tried the same function, and it worked very well at my end. Do you have any configuration which can lead to this issue?

Comment: @FaizanAli the parameter contains the slashes in urlencoded form (%2F). And it is the last route segment.

Comment: @RakeshKumar With what URL did you test it in particular?

Comment: @RakeshKumar
Not in Laravel. My Apache2 vhost config looks like this (as recommended for Laravel):
<Directory .....>
        RewriteEngine On

        # Handle Authorization Header
       ....

        # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
        RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]

        # Send Requests To Front Controller...
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
        RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</Directory>

Comment: @RakeshKumar is right, there is no error in your code.

Comment: Are you using Apache? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4390436/need-to-allow-encoded-slashes-on-apache

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález Yes I do. Thanks for the link, I'll try the NE flag for RewriteRule next time I'm on the server.

Answer (score -1):

I tried this in my laravel 8 project.
You should pass as param, the Slash (/) not it's encoding 2%F.

```
Route::get('/testslash/{param}', function($param) {
    return $param;
})->where('param', '.*');
```

so the param you pass is test/test and not test2%Ftest.

Comment: That's not what I want to do. The slash is part of the url parameter and not a url delimiter and is therefore encoded.